# Placing 2 images side by side with Text overlay

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I want to place 2 images side by side with text overlay.
Here is the code for 1 image with text, i want to place 2 images side by side with text overlay which is shown on the bottom.

[image]

And the code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/overlay_margin"
        android:background="#FFF" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/salogo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="#7000"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:shadowColor="#000"
                android:shadowDx="3"
                android:shadowDy="3"
                android:shadowRadius="6"
                android:text="Styling Android"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="A guide to applying styles and themes to Android apps"
                android:textColor="#CCC"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the view like this

[image]

Comment: What's bothering you, What problem do you have?

Comment: android:orientation="vertical" for placing image and text. But for placing 2 images side by side it should be android:orientation="horizontal". I dont know how to place it.

Comment: You want two blocks side by side with a different text overlay above both images like picture at bottom or two images side by side with one text over both

Comment: Yes, 2 different images with 2 different text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `include` from here [Improving Layouts : Reusing](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

You will need to use your layout like this. If you want to add more stuff, wrap the MainLayout.xml root to another `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`

Create your main layout that you will call on your `Activity`, Extract the "Hello Android" to your strings file:
MainLayout.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width=”match_parent”
    android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <TextView
         android:layout_width=”match_parent”
         android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
         android:Text="Hello Android"/>
     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width=”match_parent”
         android:layout_height=”wrap_content”
         android:orientation="horizontal">
         <include layout="@Layout/myTextImageLayout"
                 android:layout_weight="1" />
         <include layout="@Layout/myTextImageLayout" 
                 android:layout_weight="1" />
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create another layout where most of your stuff will go :
myTextImageLayout.xml (your current layout)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/overlay_margin"
    android:background="#FFF" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/salogo" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#7000"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:shadowColor="#000"
            android:shadowDx="3"
            android:shadowDy="3"
            android:shadowRadius="6"
            android:text="Styling Android"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="A guide to applying styles and themes to Android apps"
            android:textColor="#CCC"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```